# Connection to MS SQL Server from smart device

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have the trouble with connection to MS SQL Server from Smart Device Project in Visual Studio 2008.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = "Data Source=SERVER-5;Initial Catalog=MydB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=5";

        DataTable data;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            try
            {
                var sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from pri_date", connection);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                data = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                var exc = ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to run this code in Visual Studio and I'm getting the error "Specified SQL server not found: SERVER-5" .

When I tried to launch this code in Windows application everything worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that it's a name resolution issue.  If you use the server's IP address instead of the name, it will likely work.  If that does work, then you need to make sure you have the DNS Server properly set for your device's network adapter.